# how to get test name dynamically

Tags: junit, fitnesse

I have suite of fitnesse test cases from junit. and I would like to log the test or page name(from setup()) for each test case. Please let me know how I can find test or page name dynamically with sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Let me add more info. When I run this test, http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample , Then I want to print "TwoMinuteExample" in my log. Please advise how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

JUnit's [TestName rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) is what you're looking for.

```
 public class TestNameTest {
    @Rule
    public TestName name= new TestName();

    @Test
    public void testA() {
            assertEquals("testA", name.getMethodName());
    }
 }
```

Comment: added comment with my question. I tried this approach and name gets values of "org.junit.rules.TestName@385cb0".